# jQuery fade in child after child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadein, children

For some reason, I know this is possible without using selectors or classes or identifiers, I just cant figure it out.

I have some `div`s nested in other `div`s and I want to fade each one in, one after the other, from the shallowest `div` to the deepest `div`.

I initially though `.each()` or `.children()` but I just cant figure it out. I'm not sure how it would be written.

But, for some reason, I have a strong feeling, it could be accomplished with a short simple script, can anybody help me figure that out?

Here's a fiddle which should be more understandable. http://jsfiddle.net/3z9Bf/

---

Don't let the fiddle confuse you though. I am not trying to just `.fadeIn` the first `div` I began writing the script myself when I realized I couldn't do it myself.

Comment: Are you sure it is from the shalowest to the deepest? Beause before the process gets to the deepest div, the divs above will be closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a simple plugin:

```
$.fn.cascadeChildren = function (speed) {
    var $children = this.children();

    if ( ! $children.length ) return;

    speed = speed || 300;

    $children.animate({ opacity: 1 }, speed, function () {
        $(this).cascadeChildren(speed);
    });
};
```

Use it as follows:

```
$('#element').cascadeChildren();
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GUFzc/

Comment: That's really nice! Exactly what I wanted but I'm looking for the simplest possible script. I'm not even caring for function-plugins etc. There's something about the project that give me an inkling that I can accomplish it with a three liner. However, if nobody else responds, obviously I would be wrong and I'll give you the credit.